# What happend to HttpMessageConverters in spring boot 2?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring boot `2.1.3.RELEASE` and in [the docs about Message serialization](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-message-converters), there is a reference to `HttpMessageConverters`:

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConverters;
```

However, this class seems to be dropped in spring boot `2.0.0.RELEASE` (was available in `1.5.19.RELEASE`).

How can I add custom message converters in spring boot 2?

Comment: It's [still here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.3.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/http/HttpMessageConverters.html) in Spring Boot 2.1.3.RELEASE.

Comment: @BackSlash But if I add that maven dependency, the import does not work... It however works with `1.5.19.RELEASE`.

Comment: Ah it seems to have a different package: `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConverters;` (`http.HttpMessageConverters` instead of `web.HttpMessageConverters`)

Answer (score 2):

It was replaced by

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConverters
```

The docs seem to be wrong...

Comment: Thanks for tracking down the problem. I've opened https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/16017 to fix the documentation.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Cool, thanks! I wanted to open a report myself, but did not find a place for it (I was looking in the header and footer of the documentation page for some "feedback"-link or similar). Thanks!