# error: cannot find symbol import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConverters;

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I am trying to build the Java 17 Project which is using Gradle 7.3 and Spring Boot.I am getting below error for the HttpMessageConverters since this class is not found in jar:

```
error: cannot find symbol
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConverters;
```

Is HttpMessageConverters class deprecated in spring boot 2.0.0 Release onwards
^

HttpMessageConverters issue need to be fixed

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54823112/17105581), it was replaced by `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConverters`